# Cannot remove a class hidden by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like hide a div when it is loaded and show it when a button is clicked, but what I get is that the div only shows for a short while and hides again. Am I doing it correctly with the CSS class or is there anything special about `display:none;`?

## ***HTML***

---

```html
<div id="message">
    <div class="item-user hid">
        <a href="">something</a> 
    </div>

    <a class="btn-user" href="">button</a>
</div>
```

## ***CSS***

---

```css
.hid {
    display: none; 
}
```

## ***JS***

---

```js
<script>
    //jquery is loaded already

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#message .btn-user').click(function(){
            $('#message .item-user').removeClass('hid');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: The problem is just as Felix has captured, his answer works well. @RobinvdA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent the default action of your anchor:

```
$('#message .btn-user').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#message .item-user').removeClass('hid');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGULb/)**

Comment: It works, cool. I want to provide some background of my code. I was using Bootstrap, and button can be defined with tag 'a' or 'button', that's why I have met this problem. Can you explain a bit about why is that when I click on it, it first show for a second and then disappear?

Comment: Because the href of the button is empty, the page reloads. So when you click on the button, first the class is removed `$('#message .item-user').removeClass('hid');` and then the page reloads. `e.preventDefault();` prevents the default behavior of an element

Answer (score 2):

use this http://jsfiddle.net/3Cp75/

for

```
<div id="message">
    <div class="item-user hid">
        <a href="">something</a> 
    </div>

    <a class="btn-user" href="">button</a>
</div>
```

*why we are using preventdefault*:

```
  **Prevent a submit button from submitting a form**
```

otherwise if you dnt want it remove href

link  http://jsfiddle.net/3Cp75/1/

Comment: It's not a great answer because you don't explain why the OP should do it this way.

Comment: @AvinashGarg:  or there is no difference in both,so when you see a right answer,please support it,or if you have an improved answer you could post it,otherwise you should support the right answer

Comment: @SajadLfc i havent seen the previous answer .. ok my answer was not good coz not having explanation now its ok....

Answer (score 2):

Update your anchor tag "href" attr to "javascript:void(0);". This will prevent the default action and leave it to manage the action with javacript.

Or you can go with the

[event.preventdefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault)

This also do same but you will handle the action in javascript function.